# Insect identification (SP/Brazil)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found this insect in São Paulo/Brazil. Its length is ~2cm

Any help to identify this insect would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Also see my [video](https://youtu.be/MSGW44S-zLY)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it's a type of firefly, belongs to the order of 'Coleoptera' (beetles), suborder of 'Polyphaga', family of 'Lampyridae' (firefly beetles). It's quite similar to the 'Photinus obscurellus' species (and probably the same species too), however it doesn't always have a black head like yours, however, articles have suggested that  firefly species in Brazil (Sao Paulo State) have 'adapted to mesophyl tropical forests, secondary growths, marshy areas, and open fields' (source = https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233574632_Fireflies_Coleoptera_Lampyridae_from_Southeastern_Brazil_Habitats_Life_History_and_Bioluminescence).

This adaption may have led to species having black heads as oppose the more colourful head of the Photinus obscurellus. However the bodies and the dimensions match yours very closely.[image]

This image is from Google Images (more specifically : http://bugguide.net/node/view/194980/bgimage)

Comment: Why don't you add a picture of Photinus obscurellus as reference? It will be easier for OP and other readers to comprehend your answer.

Comment: Alrighty then, done

Comment: The insect in the picture doesn't have a colourful head(prothorax)? Also mention the source if the picture isn't taken by you.

Comment: Yeah, I just found this photo know on google images, most are slightly different bum ur it is the same species, that's why I edited my answer to 'usually colourful'

Comment: Note that the systematics of fireflies is in a bit of a flux. Also, @LucasDyson-Diaz, please cite the source of the "articles" you've read (especially the one that you quote) and provide proper reference to the image if possible. It's always good to see where you got your info since the internet is so full of deviously wrong info